# The query has been canceled because the estimated cost of this query (27195) exceeds the configured threshold of 3000 in SQL Server 2014

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, performance, linq-to-entities

I am using LINQ query to get rows with joining multiple tables and also used let keyword to get the list of rows for displaying multiple values in a display column. What's wrong with this linq query?

[ImageLink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNx3f.png)

```
(from app in _dbContext.Appointments
 join patient in _dbContext.Patients on app.PatientID equals patient.ID
 join doc in _dbContext.Doctors on app.DoctorID equals doc.ID
 join avail in _dbContext.DoctorsAvailabilities on app.AvailabilityID equals avail.ID
 join loc in _dbContext.OfficeLocations on app.LocationID equals loc.ID
 join state in _dbContext.CategoryDetails on loc.USState equals state.ItemID into StateGroup
 from state in StateGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
 join appoint in _dbContext.CategoryDetails on app.Status equals appoint.ItemID into AppointmentStatusGroup
 from appoint in AppointmentStatusGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()

 let reasonVisit = (from v in _dbContext.DoctorAppointmentVisitReasons
                    join c in _dbContext.CategoryDetails on v.ReasonID equals c.ItemID
                    where c.CategoryID == CatergoryConstant.ReasonofVisit && v.AppointmentID == app.ID
                    select c.MasterData).ToList()
 join appointmentSource in _dbContext.CategoryDetails on app.AppointmentSource equals appointmentSource.ItemID into AppointmentSourceGroup
 from appointmentSource in AppointmentSourceGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
 let getReport = (from st in _dbContext.DoctorReportStatus
                  join cat in _dbContext.CategoryDetails on st.ReportStatus equals cat.ItemID
                  where st.StatusID == StatusConstant.Active && st.AppointmentID == app.ID
                  select new DoctorReportStatusViewModel() { ReportStatusText = cat.MasterData, ReportStatus = st.ReportStatus, AppointmentID = st.AppointmentID }).ToList()

 let specility = (from s in _dbContext.DoctorSpecialities
                  join c in _dbContext.CategoryDetails on s.SpecialitiesID equals c.ItemID
                  where c.CategoryID == CatergoryConstant.DoctorSpeciality && s.DoctorID == doc.ID
                  select c.MasterData).ToList()
```

Comment: Post your code, not image.

Comment: Note that you have a typo `CatergoryConstant`

Comment: The problem is a bad context design. Not SQL Server, not MVC, not performance. You *SHOULDN'T* use joins, that's the job of the ORM. Define proper relations between the entities and let the ORM do its job

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That won't help since EF will implement navigation with joins if the joins are the problem.

Comment: Your query is incomplete - where is the `select`?

Comment: @NetMage that *will* help because the query will become a *lot* clearer, with far less duplication and no attempt to load everything in a single query. It will probably eliminate unwanted joins - it's hard to say whether all those joins are necessary. It's hard to read that query period, even if it wasn't missing important parts

Comment: @NetMage on the other hand ORMs aren't meant for reporting scenarios. The OP should create a well written SQL view if not proper reporting tables.

Comment: Come to think of it, for the cost to be so high the tables probably have no indexes. Or some entities map to badly written views that map to tables with no indexes